# What is the difference between reg-event-db, reg-event-fx and reg-event-ctx in Re-frame?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

There are *3 event fns* in **Re-frame**, I can do the same thing with both `reg-event-db` and `reg-event-fx`.

What is the main difference between `reg-event-db`, `reg-event-fx` and `reg-event-ctx`?

When should I use `reg-event-fx` over `reg-event-db` or vice versa.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short answer: they represent three levels of abstraction for registering event handlers.

`reg-event-db` is a more focused, limited version of `reg-event-fx`. When your handler is only concerned with the `db` value, then `reg-event-db` is the most convenient to use; you could write the same handler with `reg-event-fx` but you'd have to get the `:db` value out of the handler's input. This is the most common case for registering event handlers.

If your handler needs to access co-effects/produce effects then you'd use `reg-event-fx` and get the `:coeffects` value (and `:db` if necessary) from the handler's input. A common use case is when you need to access browser storage (e.g. cookies, local storage) but want to keep your handlers free of side-effects. The docs have an [example](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/Coeffects.md#a-motivating-example) of this.

`reg-event-ctx` is an even lower-level type of event handler which receives the entire [context](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/Interceptors.md#what-is-context), but this is rarely what you'd want to use to register an event handler. From the docs: `This form of registration is almost never used.`

This is an example context map:

```
{:coeffects {:event [:some-id :some-param]
             :db    <original contents of app-db>}

 :effects   {:db    <new value for app-db>
             :dispatch  [:an-event-id :param1]}

 :queue     <a collection of further interceptors>
 :stack     <a collection of interceptors already walked>}
```

- `reg-event-db` handlers are only given `:coeffects -> :db` value, and their return value informs `:effects -> :db`
- `reg-event-fx` handlers are given the entire `:coeffects` value, and their return value informs `:effects`
- `reg-event-ctx` handlers are passed (and return) this entire context map